# compilation error Black Berry WebWordks SDK

Tags: blackberry-playbook, blackberry-webworks

i am unable to compile the code using bbwp tool.

Take a look at the screenshot and please point-out what i am doing wrong

Thanks [image]

In the screen-shot

1. WARNING: about  element, i know its in config.xml but not confirm what to put in it.
2. ERROR: about jvm.dll well that file exists on the path, i have checked it.

Comment: Did you found the solution for this problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while found out that MSCR71.dll was the problem, placed it in windows/system32 in Win7 but did not worked but worked on winxp.

Comment: hi.. i can't find the file in Win7.. I am also facing the same problem. Can you help me..

Comment: as i mentioned it in answer that it did not worked in win7 but worked in winxp.

Answer (score 0):

### Fix for Windows 7 and Windows 8

If you are having this issue and are in Windows 7 64bit or Windows 8 64bit, I have tackled this problem successfully using the following steps:

- Install the latest **32bit** JDK (*not jre*) from Oracle
- Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, for example:

  Set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre

After doing the above steps, you should no longer see the error.

**Note**: I was working with the following versions:

- BlackBerry WebWorks SDK for TabletOS 2.2.0.5
- PhoneGap 2.1
- Java JDK 1.7
- OS: Windows 8 RTM 64bit

Answer (score 0):

- If you have a `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable (maybe from a previous
  setting), it must be set to point to the new jre folder that belongs to
  the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK install folder.
- Also in the `%PATH%` environment variable, if you have a path that points to a
  previous JDK or JRE \bin folder (for java.exe) you'll have to
  change that one to point to the new JRE\bin folder from the
  BlackBerry WebWorks SDK install folder.
- Also with a text editor check the `bbwp.properties` file (the file is in
  \bbwp\bin folder from the BlackBerry WebWorks SDK install folder),
  there is a section for java, it has to be either empty like
  `<java></java>` or contain the full path to the \jre for the BlackBerry
  WebWorks SDK install folder just like the one for JAVA_HOME

Sample "BlackBerry WebWorks SDK install folder \jre" based on screenshot above:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks Packager for PlayBook\jre"
```